# How to debug nsis script? 3.05-2 gives error: Error: unterminated string parsing line at macro:_IncludeStrFunction

Tags: nsis

How to debug nsis script?

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 which seems to update nsis from v3.04-1 to v3.05-2. Now I get an error with my script:

```
# makensis installer.nsi 
Processing config: /etc/nsisconf.nsh
Processing script file: "installer.nsi" (UTF8)
Error: unterminated string parsing line at macro:_IncludeStrFunction:7
Error in macro _IncludeStrFunction on macroline 7
!include: error in script: "../src/other/EnvVarUpdate.nsh" on line 49
Error in script "installer.nsi" on line 2 -- aborting creation process
```

My script is this:

```
OutFile speedata-publisher-windows-386-3.9.14-installer.exe
!include "../src/other/EnvVarUpdate.nsh"
InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\speedata-publisher
DirText "This will install speedata Publisher on your computer. Choose a directory"

Section
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
RMDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR
File /r /tmp/publisher-git/build/speedata-publisher\*.*
${EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "A" "HKCU" "$INSTDIR\bin"
WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe
MessageBox MB_OK "Run speedata Publisher with 'sp' on the command.com prompt"
SectionEnd


Section "Uninstall"
${un.EnvVarUpdate} $0 "PATH" "R" "HKCU" "$INSTDIR\bin"
RMDir /r /REBOOTOK $INSTDIR
SectionEnd
```

and the `EnvVarUpdate.nsh` is from https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Environmental_Variables:_append,_prepend,_and_remove_entries

The line 49 in this script is `!insertmacro _IncludeStrFunction StrTok`

The output of my command with the previous version 3.04-1 is:

```
Processing config: /etc/nsisconf.nsh
Processing script file: "build/installer.nsi" (UTF8)

Processed 1 file, writing output (x86-ansi):

Output: "/tmp/publisher-git/build/speedata-publisher-windows-386-3.9.14-installer.exe"
Install: 2 pages (128 bytes), 1 section (4120 bytes), 1139 instructions (31892 bytes), 647 strings (11565 bytes), 1 language table (230 bytes).
Uninstall: 1 page (128 bytes), 1 section (4120 bytes), 385 instructions (10780 bytes), 100 strings (1387 bytes), 1 language table (194 bytes).
Datablock optimizer saved 650630 bytes (~1.8%).

Using zlib compression.

EXE header size:               75264 / 76288 bytes
Install code:                  10537 / 45255 bytes
Install data:               34526923 / 62531730 bytes
Uninstall code+data:            2665 / 3163 bytes
CRC (0xFE2E922E):                  4 / 4 bytes

Total size:                 34615393 / 62656440 bytes (55.2%)
```

I am not really into nsis scripts, so I would like to know how to find where the problem could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a change to how StrFunc works internally and the 3rd-party EnvVarUpdate.nsh file from the Wiki is incompatible with it.

As discussed [here](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=455616), you could try fixing EnvVarUpdate.nsh by changing  `!define un.${StrFuncName} "${Un${StrFuncName}}"` to 
`!define un.${StrFuncName} '${Un${StrFuncName}}'`.

Instead of manually patching that file, I would recommend that you use the [EnVar plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/EnVar_plug-in) as a replacement.

Comment: Thank you very much.